# How to think about this code design in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm learning react and having some trouble getting my head around some code design. I have a Session component that has several Activity components in my project. In the Session component I also have a Timeline component and I need to show the total duration of all of the events. So I need to have the start time for each of the Activities in the Session component and the end time of the last. I know of "lifting state up", but I find it a little strange in my OO way of thinking from C++ to store the data in the parent and not where it "belongs". What if I later need some other data from the activity.. Then I would lift parts of the Activity data up and store some of it in the Activity.. seems quiet messy?

I thought of also having a ActivityData object and store a list of them in the Session and pass that in to each of the activity to display it there. Another way I thought about would be to have a SessionModel object and a ActivityModel object and have this seperate from the component all together and pass these models in for rendering in the component.

I am also just getting into typescript and moving my code into that. I was thinking that I could define a custom ActivityData type in the same file as the Activity component and still store the list in the Session, but then at least its more explicit that the data belongs to the activity.

What is the right (or React) way of doing this?

Comment: TLoe, did my answer help?

Comment: Yes thank you :) Had to do some other stuff so been away from my problem :)

Comment: no worries. thanks for accepting answer :) have a good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in your thinking and yes it isn't necessarily an OO way of doing things but more of a functional programming approach

Each component can have state, and it should store that state in it's own component. If that state is then needed by another component you can pass it down as a `prop`. However, if it isn't a child component that needs it then like you said you should lift state up.

The next problem happens when your app starts to grow. So then you need to make some choices. You should split your components up so they don't get too big. You can have some more logical components and then have some presentational components that don't handle logic but essentially just take props and render the views from you.

However, your app is still growing so at this point you might want to invest some time in introducing a state management tool to your app. React has the [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)
api built into so you can use that. or you could use a library like[redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started). Redux is particularly good at abstracting state to a "global" store and you each component can "connect" to the store to access the state. Really good for apps where you have lots of shared state and lots of components need to know about similar pieces of state

In terms of Typescript then it's certainly a wise idea to include that as the language is heading that way. You can keep types in the same file or keep them in the same directory but have a `.types.ts` file that you import into your code and declare your types/interfaces in there